# Mocking a concrete class with a virtual method

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute, autofixture

I want to test a class that depends on another class with the virtual method.

```
class DepClass
{
  public virtual string Get() => "";
}

class HostClass
{
  private _c;
  public Host(DepClass c){ _c = c; }

  public string Magic() => _c.Get();
}
```

Now I want to test the `HostClass` with Autofixture + NSubstitute.
My expectation:

```
Fixture.Freeze<DepClass>().Get().ReturnsForAnyArg("123");
var sut = Fixture.Create<HostClass>();
var res = sut.Magic(); //should be 123
```

As a fact, when I do `Freeze().Get().Returns()` the real `Get` method is being called.
How to customize Autofixture to mock all virtual methods?

Would be great not to discuss interface vs virtual methods, etc

*Update*
This does not work:

```
Fixture.Freeze<DepClass>().Get().ReturnsForAnyArgs("123");
```

At the same time, this works:

```
Substitute.For<DepClass>().Get().ReturnsForAnyArgs("123");
```

**In addition to the answer**
Another approach that might be not fit your needs: in my case, I expect that only direct dependencies can have virtual methods. all dependencies of the lower level will be mocked.

As result, I decided to go in a bit more specific way. The code below is an example, so you might be want to modify it before using it in your solution.

```
abstract class UnitTestBase<T>
{
  protected IFixture Fixture { get; private set; }
  protected IList<Type> ProxyTypes {get; private set;}
  protected CreateSut(): T => Fixt.Create<T>();

  [SetUp]
  protected virtual Setup()
  {
    ProxyTypes = new List<Type>();
    Fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new CompositeCustomization(
        new AutoNSubstituteCustomization {
            ConfigureMembers = true,
            GenerateDelegates = true
        })
    );

    SetupTypesToProxy();
    Fixture.Customizations.Add(new SubstituteRelay(new ProxyExactTypesSpecification(ProxyTypes)));
  }

  protected virtual void SetupTypesToProxy()
    => typeof(T)
        .GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .SelectMany(ctorInfo => ctorInfo
            .GetParameters()
            .Select(paramInfo => paramInfo.ParameterType)
            .Where(ShouldProxy))
        .ForEach(t => ProxyTypes.Add(t));

  private static bool ShouldProxy(Type type)
    => !type.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface && !type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract;
}

internal class ProxyExactTypesSpecification: IRequestSpecification
{
    public ProxyExactTypesSpecification(
        IEnumerable<Type> types
        )
    {
        _proxyTypes = types ?? Type.EmptyTypes;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(
        object request
        )
    {
        Argument.NotNull(request, nameof(request));

        if (request is Type type)
            return _proxyTypes.Contains(type);

        return false;
    }

    private readonly IEnumerable<Type> _proxyTypes;
}
```

Comment: You may take a look on the [Substitute] attribute: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/pull/430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `DepClass` is neither an interface nor an abstract type, by default, AutoFixture will not rely on a mocking framework to create the instance, and will use the actual constructor from the type.

Since NSubstitute does not have the equivalent of `Mock<T>` or `Fake<T>` from other popular mocking frameworks, AutoFixture had to provide a special specimen builder, called `SubstituteRelay`, to fill in the gap. You can use this class as any other specimen builder to instruct the Fixture to return a mock when a specific type instance is requested.

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
fixture.Customizations
    .Add(new SubstituteRelay(new ExactTypeSpecification(typeof(DepClass))));
```

This construction is a bit lengthy so you could create a generic relay to shorten the syntax.

```cs
public class SubstituteRelay<T> : CompositeSpecimenBuilder
{
    public SubstituteRelay()
        : base(new SubstituteRelay(new ExactTypeSpecification(typeof(T))))
    {
    }
}
```

You should be able to write your test something like.

```cs
[Fact]
public void ReturnsExpectedValue()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new SubstituteRelay<DepClass>());
    fixture.Freeze<DepClass>().Get().ReturnsForAnyArgs("1234");
    var sut = fixture.Create<HostClass>();

    var actual = sut.Magic();

    Assert.Equal("1234", actual);
}
```

To get closer to your intended API, you can create your own extension method that abstracts away the two lines of code that register the relay and freeze the instance.